# Definition of a wave packet

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, definition, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In Shankar's QM book page 168, the author stated

> a wave packet is any wave function with reasonably well-defined
> position and momentum.

What does he mean by resonably well-defined position and momentum? What are some examples of well defined/ not well-defined position and momentum?

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, one can speak of a *Gaussian wave packet*:
$$
\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma_x^2)^{1/4}}e^{-\frac{(x-vt)^2}{4\sigma_x^2}},
$$
which has finite uncertainty in momentum and finite uncertainty in position (Which can be easily calculated as an exercise).

On the other hand, a plane wave is not a wave packet, as it has infinite uncertainty in position. Same can be said about a state with a well-defined momentum. Finally, one would usually not consider as wave packets wave functions with multiple maxima in position or momentum space.